# Spring boot and hibernate mysql database connection keep on disconnecting

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-boot

My web app now is running perfectly and persisting the data to mysql database. One thing only I cannot understand with the connection is, it drops the connection on the database after some time and I need to keep on stopping and starting again the Tomcat to keep the connection active with the app. 
Is there any session time out  I need to set in tomcat web server or in mysql database?

Below is my application.properties in spring boot.

```
debug=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG


Below is the exception:

Exception: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
```

Appreciate your help.

Donald

Comment: Post your jdbc connection url please. Must be something like this
`url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hposg`

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622233/hibernate-property-to-keep-connections-alive) helps

Comment: spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. just add to your application.properties

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```